# Object as static property

Tags: php

I am trying to create a static property with a `DOMDocument`. However, I am getting the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW)
```

Here's the declaration:

```
protected static $domd = new DOMDocument();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't assign a new instance of a class to a static property

Answer (score 0):

"Like any other PHP static variable, static properties may only be initialized using a literal or constant; expressions are not allowed. So while you may initialize a static property to an integer or array (for instance), you may not initialize it to another variable, to a function return value, or to an object."

You cannot assign a new instance of a class to a static property.

See [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) for details